# How to share state between users in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, multi-user

I'm building a multiplayer card game mainly in ReactJS and want to share some state between users (players).  I need each user to be able to know when it's their turn to play and see some things about other users like score and current number of cards in hand, etc.  For example, when one player's turn ends, I need the next player's app to recognize it's their turn and provide the applicable options.

It seems WebSockets or something based on it would be a good option.  I'm still learning React and other pieces so I'm trying to keep the number of technologies down for now.  I'm considering setting up rapid polling (every 200 ms, perhaps), either to an API or maybe checking against a file on the server or database entries.

Are there especially concerning performance issues or better options to get it working?  I'm also learning about AWS and Docker and intend to host on AWS, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you use firebase which is a database to send and receive data online because the states of react js are not interlaced between devices

Comment: Any other database is fine as well, though. You just need a way to persist the state between users.

Answer (score 4):

instead of sharing state between players you should explore the possibility of players sharing an instance of game object on the server.

for example :

```
game={
status:'running',
players:2,
p1:{state:'waiting'},
p2:{state:'active'}
}
```

- time complexity for common state on server will be [n]
- expected time complexity for state exchange or polling is [n^2] or more.

Comment: I hadn't thought of it in those terms, that the server can push to clients on state change.  I don't think I've stumbled upon that aspect before, but I'm still fairly unpracticed with React.

Comment: Would you have a full example to point me to?  All my searches indicate you can do things on the server and the client but nothing is really showing HOW those are managed.

Comment: if you can provide your full stack, and/or workflow i can give a better solution. in php you could use get/post variables in ur game-instance.php  to handle ajax. if its node.js backend then use the appropriate ajax call handler. the key to your problem is sending ajax calls upon event trigger in ur game...and then server process and update the state...and then users ping a url on server and acquire the changed state. and process continues untill terminate signal sent by server to all users.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm using ASP.NET Core.  The Visual Studio template for this appears to set up the React aspects to be purely client side, expecting .NET to handle the backend. 
 I'm open to others (Node.js seems a good branching), but trying not to have EVERYTHING be brand new to me.

Comment: Also, this discussion has pointed me down the right path (I think).  Server-sent events looks like a promising concept:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets won't work for you as you need one fixed party in WebSocket connection.

You could share the state peer-to-peer style with a WebRTC connection and using the DataChannel in that connection, but that's not an easy task.
(see for example: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcdatachannel)

The much more common option is to use a central data storage and either sync your state with that or just store it there in the first place.
You could use Firebase (see [answer by David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63024437/333492)) or any other kind of database.
Firebase is particularly easy to set up, though.

If you have/need/want to use an API-backend anyways, you can use pretty much any kind of database layer in that and just talk REST or GraphQL with the API to share your state between players.

Comment: It's a React (plus other stuff) learning project.  So "need" may not apply, but it's a good consideration on the API-backend.  Overall, good thoughts!

Comment: Gotcha, I fixed that to be more inclusive. I know it's just wording, but I didn't even consider the learning project/pet project where you can decide either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try serverless approach, you can look at AWS Lambda and Dynamo DB.

Comment: I started looking at AWS Amplify, specifically DataStore.  I'm using this project in part to get practice with AWS so such a route is interesting to me.